# Theme development: How to add CSS classes to menu items?

Tags: theme-development, menus

While building  a custom theme, I've been stuck on how to add a CSS class to a certain theme menu (meaning a custom menu that is associated with a theme menu position).

So far, in my template I have

```
  <?php if (has_nav_menu('main-menu')) : ?>
    <nav class="topmenu" role="navigation">
    <?php
      wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu-class'  => 'topmenu--list',
        'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
        'fallback_cb' => false,
      ));
    ?>
    </nav>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

So, I'm sort of missing a `'menu-item-class'` option in the wp_nav_menu's `$args` array. How can I pass a CSS class to each menu item?

Just to be clear, I do not want an editor to set a CSS class to each menu item manually in admin backend. I want to add the CSS class to each menu item programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nav_menu_css_class` filter which is applied to every menu item in the specified nav menu.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    $classes[] = 'your-custom-class';
    return $classes;
}
```

More info: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/add-a-custom-class-in-wordpress-menu-item-using-conditional-statements/

Answer (score 0):

From WordPress Plugin API You can use nav_menu_css_class filter example :

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Blog' ) {
        $classes[] = 'special-class';
    }
    return $classes;
 }
 add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class